# Vim - Emphasis words or lines permanently

Tags: vim

Is there a possibility to emphasis text passages, words s or single lines in a file permanently?

I'm thinking of something similar to the function in Word where you can emphasis your text selection by changing the background colour.

This would be helpful since I sometimes have code or text that I want to review later. Having a annotation command could come in quite handy.

Regards

Comment: I think the general accepted way of dealing with this is to add TODO, XXX, or FIXME markers in the document.  Those strings are usually highlighted in a way that stands out by default.  There are even scripts out there that "collect" all the spots in your file with these markers and allow you to quickly jump through them.

Comment: Since Vim is a plain text editor, "highlighting" is only possible by using some kind of overt marking. That may be a keyword such as "TODO" or markup such as `*bold*`, and then setting an appropriate syntax-highlighting `'filetype'`.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about the TODO marker. Are you aware of any plugin that let's me put a permanent marker on a whole line by clicking for example on the line number? The line should then be highlighted in a different background colour. I would prefer this way than a TODO section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2208) does exactly what you want! The [screenshots](http://www.txtfmt.webs.com/) seem encouraging enough to try it out.